# How to check branch coverage in Bullseye Coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, bullseye

I am using bullseye code coverage in order to find how much is my production code covered through unit tests.
In Bullseye Coverage Browser, I am able to see function coverage as well as conditional coverage, but there is no mention of branch coverage.
Is there a way to enable branch coverage?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/is3mX.png

In the attached image, based on a particular function (blurred for confidentiality), there are respective coverage % mentioned.

Expected branch coverage also, but could not get it.